# Difference between "particularly" and "greatly"

Tags: difference, adverbs

Can you explain what is the difference between the following sentences:

1. Indirect objects are **particularly** difficult to understand.
2. Indirect objects are **greatly** difficult to understand.

What is the difference between these words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Particularly** implies more difficult than most other objects. So it compares the degree of difficulty of indirect objects with that of other objects.

**Greatly** means **very** difficult, but does not compare the degree of difficulty with other objects, which may (or may not) be just as difficult.

Comment: In OP's cited context, ***greatly*** is hopelessly non-idiomatic, if not downright ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

The intensifier ***greatly*** is almost never used before "standard" adjectives such as ***difficult, easy, expensive, enjoyable***. It's almost entirely restricted to ***past participle verb forms used adjectivally***. OP's example #2 isn't something native speakers would ever say.

See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+greatly+%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cwas%20greatly%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20increased%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20reduced%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20surprised%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20pleased%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20improved%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20interested%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20impressed%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20admired%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cwas%20greatly%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20increased%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20reduced%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20surprised%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20pleased%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20improved%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20interested%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20impressed%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20greatly%20admired%3B%2Cc0), showing that the most common words to occur in print after *[something] **was greatly...*** are ***surprised, pleased, reduced, increased, interested, impressed, improved, admired***.

Other than that, note that ***particularly*** doesn't *exactly* mean ***very*** - it means ***notably, specifically, more than other alternatives***.